# MySql Timestamp Trigger Preventing New Inserts

Tags: mysql, triggers, timestamp

I've attempted to create a trigger to update the CREATED_DATE field of my table when a new row is inserted, but it ends up breaking the Java Application.

Basically I have an NMS that is writing to the MySql server when there is an alarm. I created the following trigger because the Java application is not applying a timestamp to alarm creation (even though there is a field for it):

```
CREATE TRIGGER alarm_timestamp AFTER INSERT on Alarm_Details FOR EACH ROW UPDATE Alarm_Details SET CREATED_DATE = NOW() WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
```

After I make this trigger, the alarms never write to the table. Then I drop the trigger and they instantly work again.

Is there a problem with the way I wrote the trigger? I'm surprised a trigger in the Sql server is preventing the application from submitting an insert query.

I have now tried to add a default value to the column with the following:

```
alter table Alarm_Details add constraint df_alarm_time default NOW()  for CREATED_DATE;
```

I get a syntax error though near 'default NOW() for CREATED_DATE.'

I also tried:

```
ALTER TABLE Alarm_Details ALTER CREATED_DATE SET DEFAULT NOW();
```

It doesn't like NOW, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  or anything. The column is set to type datetime.

I am using MySql 5.5.25.

Comment: Why not user DEFAULT value on column ?
Like:
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

INSERT INTO

Comment: I tried to alter my table and add a constraint, but I'm getting a syntax error. See my edit above.

Comment: Set the column default to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: I just updated my question as you were submitting that. I attempted to change the default to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but it gives a syntax error.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using ?

Comment: mysql-5.5.25-linux2.6-x86_64